# Regexp even number of backslashes (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I have rather hard time getting my head around regular expression, especially more complex formulas.

Currently I am writing my own markup language and am stumped by escaping. I want each special character to be "escapable", that is if `*bold*` would give me `<b>bold</b>`, then `\*bold\*` should leave it as-is, so I can do the stripping of backslashes later, but I can't think of a regular expression to convey this idea.
How can I select three groups:

1. Left asterisk if the number or BSes preceding it is even;
2. Content between asterisks;
3. Right asterisk if the number of BSes preceding it is even;

with one regular expression? I need it to be compliant with PHP's `preg_replace`.

This `\\*(\*)\S(.)+?\S\\*(\*)` would select both asterisks and content as three groups, but that doesn't check for 'evenity' and stuff.

## UPDATE:

The second paragraph has been changed to better illustrate what I meant (please don't modify it anymore because the change that was made completely missed the point).

Plus, if that makes things easier, I can first parse any double backslash into some other character, so there is only need to check for ONE backslash before asterisk.

Comment: Do you mean `\\*bold\\*` produces `*bold*`?

Comment: This looks more like a job for a *parser*, not a RegEx.

Comment: @KennyTM fixed, thanks for pointining that! @deceze I dunno, I don't see why it shouldn't be possible with Regexps considering how magical things people sometimes make with them.

Comment: Not saying it's not possible, only that it'll become a pain in the rear. :o)

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. There is also a possibility to replace all double backslashes with some other character, and then just do a check for: *asterisk not preceeded by backslash* if that makes thing easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I found answer to my own question.

First I will have to replace each `\\`, and then use expression like this:

```
(?<!\\)      #There is no backslash before...
\*           #...Asterisk

(            #Non-whitespace after first and before second asterisk
  \S .*? \S  
  |
  \S
)

(?<!\\)      #There is no backslash before...
\*           #...Asterisk
```

And from on here I can tweak it however I wish. Thanks for any input to anyone anyway :).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$rx = '/
([^\\]*|^)     # no backslash or beginning of line
\\             # one backslash
\*             # an asterisk

([^*\\]+)      # one or more characters not being asterisks or BSs

\\             # one backslash
\*             # one asterisk
               # "mx" = multiline,extended regex
/mx';
```

`preg_replace($rx, '\1\2', $content)`

Comment: It gives me error for unknown "#" and if I remove comments and whitespace it nags me about *Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 23*

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. *missing terminating ] for character class at offset 297* I added another backslash to second set of square bracket and it executes. It might be something with settings on my end. Though I think what I wrote was kind of misleading, so I updated the initial post with better clarification. Still thanks for your time!